# CSS animation doesn't fire in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation

I have a weird problem with a very simple CSS animation. It doesn't fire in Chrome and I cannot figure out why.

```
/*** SPIN BUTTON ***/
@keyframes spinbutton {
    0%   { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
    50%  { background-color: #177e78; color: #e9b817; }
    100% { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinbutton {
    0%   { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
    50%  { background-color: #177e78; color: #e9b817; }
    100% { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinbutton {
    0%   { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
    50%  { background-color: #177e78; color: #e9b817; }
    100% { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
}

@-o-keyframes spinbutton    {
     0%  { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
    50%  { background-color: #177e78; color: #e9b817; }
    100% { background-color: #e9b817; color: #177e78; }
}


.spin-button-inner-active
{
    -webkit-animation: spinbutton 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: spinbutton 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: spinbutton 1s infinite;
    animation: spinbutton 1s infinite;
}
```

and it it used on a div element

```
<div class="spin-button-inner spin-button-inner-active">SPIN!</div>
```

It plays perfectly in Firefox

Comment: It seems to work fine on Chrome too. I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome on Mac here. "Have you tried turning it off and on again?".

Comment: Hmm.. That is weird... It just don't work - might be a cache problem or something then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Animation should look like this :

```css
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
```

Add Any attributes you like